# Pythagorean Theorem Calculator using HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, pythagorean

I am trying to code a Pythagorean theorem calculator using HTML and Javascript so that it can find any of the sides given two of the sides value, so i am using if statements but it seem like i am unable to understand why it doesn't work

here are both the HTML and JavaScript codes

```js
function do_things() {
  var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a").value);
  var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b").value);
  var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c").value);
  var output = document.getElementById("output");

  if (a=0, b>0){
    var c = Math.sqrt(c*c - b*b)
    var node = document.createElement("LI");                 // Create a <li> node
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(c);              // Create a text node
    node.appendChild(textnode);                              // Append the text to <li>
    document.getElementById("output").appendChild(node);
  } else if (c=0, b>0){
    var c = Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b)
    console.log(0)
    var node = document.createElement("LI");                 // Create a <li> node
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(c);              // Create a text node
    node.appendChild(textnode);                              // Append the text to <li>
    document.getElementById("output").appendChild(node);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Calc</h1>
<p1>Calculate the Hypotnuse given the A and B value</p1>
<p>Side A: <input type="text" id="a"/></p>
<br>
<p>Side B: <input type="text" id="b"/></p>
<br>
<p>Hypotnuse: <input type="text" id="c"/></p>
<br>
 <button type="button" onclick="do_things()">Find the missing value</button>
<br>
<p id="output">The Missing hypotnuse</p>
```

Comment: `if (a = 0,` Look up basic JS syntax - `=` is assignment. Use `===` for comparison. Also, you might consider just assigning to `textContent` rather than creating / appending an actual text node, which is unnecessarily verbose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(a=0, b>0)` is not a valid condition. `a = 0` is assignment which should be either `a == 0` or `a === 0` and `,` doesn't serve as `AND` operator, `&&` does. So you need to change that condition to something like `(a === 0 && b > 0)`.

But you can simplify your code and use better conditions as well as better DOM manipulation. Here is how you can do it.

- use `Number.isNaN` to check whether the given input is actually a number
- add `<span id="output"></span>` to hold the result, it is easier to manipulate it than the whole paragraph
- just use `.textContent` if you need to add a plain text to some element

This code is guaranteed to perform a calculation if and only if exactly 2 sides are provided and the third one is `NaN` (empty, but also an invalid number)

```js
function do_things() {

  var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a").value);
  var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b").value);
  var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c").value);
  var output = document.getElementById("output");

  if (Number.isNaN(a) && !Number.isNaN(b) && !Number.isNaN(c)) {
    const a = Math.sqrt(c ** 2 - b ** 2);
    output.textContent = ' ' + a;
  }

  if (Number.isNaN(b) && !Number.isNaN(a) && !Number.isNaN(c)) {
    const b = Math.sqrt(c ** 2 - a ** 2);
    output.textContent = ' ' + b;
  }

  if (Number.isNaN(c) && !Number.isNaN(a) && !Number.isNaN(b)) {
    const c = Math.sqrt(a ** 2 + b ** 2);
    output.textContent = ' ' + c;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Calc</h1>
<p1>Calculate the Hypotnuse given the A and B value</p1>
<p>Side A: <input type="text" id="a"/></p>
<br>
<p>Side B: <input type="text" id="b"/></p>
<br>
<p>Hypotnuse: <input type="text" id="c"/></p>
<br>
 <button type="button" onclick="do_things()">Find the missing value</button>
<br>
<p >The Missing side is: <span id="output"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

'===' might return false here because you are parsing values to float which will give 0.00.